# MySQL Available Cars With multiple owners

Tags: mysql

I have a complex SQL question. We are building a car rental system. We have a car model table, a owner table and a link_model_owner table. In addition our bookings are kept in another table.

Scheme looks like this:

[image]

Now I need a query to search all available cars of a certain model. I've tried the following Query. However, this query will give multiple results if a linkId is added to the booking database and startDate and endDate are empty there.

I just want to have a list of unique available linkId's where the car is not rented out (NOW () between startDate and endDate).

Bear in mind that the booking database will expect to grow with 1000's a day.

```
SELECT link_model_owner.id,
        owners.fullName
FROM link_model_owner
LEFT JOIN bookings ON link_book_user.id = bookings.bookLinkId
INNER JOIN owners ON link_book_user.userId = owners.id
WHERE link_model_owner.isActive = '1'
  AND link_model_owner.modelid = '252'
  AND COALESCE(NOW() NOT BETWEEN bookings.startDate AND bookings.endDate, TRUE);
```

Comment: Why the startDate and endDate could be empty?

Comment: Because startDate and endDate are determined at the time the offer has been accepted. Meanwhile it is null. (And application like it is an offer).

Comment: How does the link_book_user table fit into it all? What does it do? And why do you need to link in the Owners table in the query? You're having several fields in your query that doesn't exist in your visual model above...it's not that easy to understand the logic in the query.

Comment: Does an entry in `Cars` represent an individual car (VIN 123) or a brand and type of car (Ford Fusion)? If the former, the intersection table doesn't quite make sense. The owner id can be part of the `Cars` tuple. If the latter, the intersection table doesn't quite make sense as there is no indication of how many of each type of car is owned by each owner. And the `Bookings` table doesn't seem to fit in with anything. So how is it possible to search for all available cars of a certain model when you don't show that information anywhere in your schema?

Answer (score 1):

It wasn't completely obvious what you wanted to use all tables for, especially `link_book_user`, but I focused on your main question where you wanted to get all cars that were not currently being booked, taking into consideration that startTime and endTime can be null.

In the query suggestion below I filter bookings on the date already when they're being linked in the join and then the query becomes a bit easier to construct. If a booking has null values as dates the car will be seen as free.

```
SELECT link_model_owner.id, 
        owners.fullName
FROM link_model_owner
LEFT JOIN bookings ON (link_model_owner.id = bookings.linkId 
                        AND bookings.startDate <= now() 
                        AND bookings.endDate >= now())
INNER JOIN owners ON owners.id = link_model_owner.ownerId
WHERE bookings.id IS null;
```

Note: It's important to have indexes on startDate and endDate since your database will grow quite some (as you wrote).